# Repeated Code for multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to use the same set of code in 4 view controllers. I am writing this code in `-(void)viewWillAppear`.

Is there any possibility that I can write this code once and use it in all 4 view controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a subclass of `UIViewController` with the common code, and then change each of your existing `UIViewController` subclasses to be a subclass of that new class.

Comment: this works fine for me....but i have a small doubt. If i add one more method to the base class and we use it only for 2 view controllers out of 4 which we used our base class in ...........Will it lead to any memory managing problem??

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static class and call the method from there:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
 +(void)myMethod{
@end

+(void)myMethod{
//Do my stuff  
}
```

And then you call the method from wherever you want:

```
[myClass myMethod];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in viewWillAppear in a custom class which subclass of UIViewController.

Then create that 4 classes by subclassing of your custom class.
And call `[super viewWillAppear]`.